# Can my dishwasher lacking a 'high loop' cause it to fill with dirty water, even if it happens hours after I last ran it?

Tags: dishwasher

My dishwasher runs and drains fine. But later (hours later), there will be standing water in it. Sometimes a little, sometimes a lot, enough to flow out onto the floor. I noticed we don't have a high loop in our line. But I feel like lacking the high loop would cause water backup immediately. Not hours later. Am I wrong in this assumption? Could my issue of the washer slowly filling up with dirty water be caused by not having this high loop?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You should [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you know how the site operates with up votes for helpful answers.

Comment: It sounds like the kitchen sink is draining into your sink

Answer (score 3):

Not having a high loop in the drain line could be causing this issue. I'm guessing that your drain connects into your disposal. In that situation if you don't have a high loop when you run your disposal or empty water from the sink on the disposal side it could back up into the dishwasher.
It's easy enough to set up a high loop if there is enough slack in the drain line. Simply loop it up as high as possible. Be careful not to kink it. You can attach it to the inside of the cabinet wall or under the countertop with a clip or zip tie.
Some local codes require the installation of an air gap vent on dw drain lines for the above reason. You might want to check. If one is required it would be a good idea to have one installed. That will solve your problem.
 [image]

Comment: They could get rid of the disposal hook up if they have one. Never been a fan of that.+

Comment: The water will still be there, even if we haven't used the sink. We'll walk away from the kitchen for a few hours, come back, and it's full of water.

Comment: If your dw is draining completely and then water comes back into it, it has to be coming back in through the drain line. The only other possibility is a faulty inlet valve that could be leaking fresh water into the dw but I think this is unlikely. I know it's hard to tell but does the water in the bottom of the dw appear fresh or does it appear to be gray water backing up from the drain line?

Comment: It's definitely grey, used water. It smells pretty gross sometimes.

Comment: The only reason I thought that it might not be backing up from the drain line is because of how long it takes to fill up with water. I figured if it was a drain line issue, it would happen immediately after a wash. 

Also because of the amount of water. It's enough to fill up the bottom of the dishwasher then leak out onto the floor. I would've thought drain water from the drain line would only leave a little bit at the bottom of the washer.

Comment: If it smells gross it's drain water. Without a high loop in the drain line water is going to sit in that line until pressure, either air or water or gravity, forces it one way or the other. There's nowhere else grey water could come from. I think the solution is to take one of the suggestions I made above. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If the dishwasher drain  is lower than other drain points,  water from the sink or whatever could flow back into the dishwasher.  To test this,  (assuming there's a kitchen sink on the same waste line),  fill the sink full & let it all drain at once.  See if water flows into the dishwasher.

Note that you don't report water leaking out of the dishwasher **during** operation, so clearly the drain pump in the dishwasher is working properly.  Now, assuming that you don't have a seriously leaky input valve on the dishwasher, my first guess above is probably right.  (Obviously when the dishwasher is off, the drain pump wouldn't empty water that entered from any source whatsoever)

Comment: The water will still be there, even if we haven't used the sink. We'll walk away from the kitchen for a few hours, come back, and it's full of water.

Comment: Yes, the dishwasher has to be running to drain the water out of the dishwater.

Comment: Yeah but I'm saying it happens even when I'm not actively running the sink during this period. I'll leave my kitchen for a few hours and come back and there will be water in there. Could this still be the cause? Can the water from the sink be delayed in going into the dishwasher, or does it happen as you run the water?

Answer (score 0):

My assumption that you don't have a high loop is indicative that you do not have an air vent installed between the dishwasher and the drain pipe.   Without the air vent which would be at the top of the "high loop", water from the sink is draining into the dishwasher.  Each time you use the sink, drain water is draining into the dishwasher, slowing building up the level of water in the dishwater.  It is the air vent with the "high loop" that stops the water from flowing from the sink into the dishwasher.

Comment: The water will still be there, even if we haven't used the sink. We'll walk away from the kitchen for a few hours, come back, and it's full of water.

Comment: That is correct.  Water is draining into the dishwasher.  Until you run the dishwasher to "pump" out the water, the water will remain.  A dishwasher uses a pump to drain the water.  While the dishwasher is off-cycle, water is continously being drained into the dishwasher.

Comment: Yeah but I'm saying it happens even when I'm not actively running the sink during this period. I'll leave my kitchen for a few hours and come back and there will be water in there. Could this still be the cause? Can the water from the sink be delayed in going into the dishwasher, or does it happen as you run the water?

Comment: @AKD the water is not necessarily coming from the kitchen sink. If you have a partial blockage somewhere downstream then it could be coming from any plumbing fixture in the house which is at the same level or above your dishwasher.

Comment: Oh, interesting! I'm in condos and there are people above me, that be a cause? Honestly since there was no correlation with it filling up when we ran our dishwasher, sink, washing machine, or shower. I thought it might be the neighbors above us' water. Is this possible?

Comment: The cause has been stated.  Do you have a properly installed dishwasher drain with the air-vent?  This will prevent any water backflowing into the dishwasher.  All the other questions about, when, how, source is irrevalent.